# retrieve address using MKReverseGeocoder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, geocoding, mkreversegeocoder

I am trying to retrieve the user address using MKReverseGeocoder. It works fine, but I am not getting the address in the proper format.

code:

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark{
    NSLog(@"Geocoder completed");
    NSLog(@"%@",[placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"]);
}
```

Output:

```
(
    "Almungev\U00e4gen 33",
    "Tempe, AZ 85281",
    USA
)
```

Why am i getting those strange characters in street name ? How can i change it to a readable format?

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
  - (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark

   {
   Nsstring*subLocalityStr= placemark.subLocality;
   Nsstring*subAdministrativeAreaStr= placemark.subAdministrativeArea;

   }
```

similarly you can get using dot notation which will give list of available methods from that you can select what you want ..

Comment: I want the complete address. So i get each and append them later?

Comment: Isnt there an simple way to get the entire address, rather than appending each string ?

Comment: sorry ,i find this alone possible. you can get entire address if you follow above